# Pymongo how can i update objects inside an array without creating duplicates

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

This is the data i have

```
"_id": 5897
"data" = [
    {
       "_id": 'a',
       "activity" : 89
       "inventory": [{"food": "5"}]
    },
    {
       "_id": 'b',
       "activity" : 25
       "inventory": [{"food": "6"}]
    },
    {
       "_id": 'c',
       "activity" : 53
       "inventory": [{"food": "2"}]
    }
]
```

i get the data in a list format so i was wondering how i could update the docs inside data without repeating the docs again

i tried this

```
for data in allData: // all data is a list that contains all docs i got from user this can have old and new docs as well
        mydb.update_one({'_id': userID}, {'$addToSet': {"data": data}})
```

but this creates a duplicate of all the existing data
any help is appriciated

```
allData = {
   "_id": 'a',
   "activity" : 92
   "inventory": [{"food": "8"}]
},
{
   "_id": 'b',
   "activity" : 50
   "inventory": [{"food": "6"}]
},
{
   "_id": 'd',
   "activity" : 92
   "inventory": [{"food": "1"}]
}
```

this the data i get from user i could get an **extra** or **less**

then

```
"_id": 5897
"data" = 
    {
       "_id": 'a',
       "activity" : 92
       "inventory": [{"food": "8"}]
    },
    {
       "_id": 'b',
       "activity" : 50
       "inventory": [{"food": "6"}]
    },
    {
       "_id": 'd',
       "activity" : 92
       "inventory": [{"food": "1"}]
    }
```

This is what should happen to data
if there is an update -> update the object
if there are deletetions delete the object
if there are no change even inside the object don't change any thing

Comment: allData contains new docs, old docs as well as updated docs as if the user activity changed from 53->89

Comment: Please provide `allData` and the expected result of this update

Comment: @nimrodserok i edited the post as per you asking

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
db.collection.update_one(
  {_id: userID}, {$set: {data: allData}}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jBI4r7ECohG)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for the question asked and the schema/workflow described in it, so it should be accepted. But just to add on here, I think @Sam may want to consider trying to track and apply updates in a more targeted manner if possible. Replacing the entire array on every update seems excessive. Certainly it may not be possible to do, and if the arrays are small then it probably won't matter anyway. But the database will have to keep rewriting this full array which can be expensive under the right circumstances.

Comment: i see thanks for the answer any other way to store the data so i can check for changes and then update the changed docs?

Comment: There is a difference between checking the changes and update the changed docs...If you want to check the changes , you can use `findOneAndUpdate`. If you want to update multiple documents there are several ways of doing it. If you want to update only the items that are actually different inside `data`, as @user20042973
suggested, there are ways to do that as well. You need to be more specific here...

Comment: can i find and update a single doc for instance find the object in the `data` for 
`"_id" : "a"` and update the whole object with/without changing its position in the list @nimrodserok

Comment: In this case use something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ym2cbSQb2GB), with `$[<identifier>]`